# Maven dependency to apache commons-text?

Tags: java, apache-commons, maven-dependency

I would like to include a Maven dependency on the apache [commons-text](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/commons-text/) project. 
I tried adding this dependency to my pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
        <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

And including the following repository:

```
    <repository>
        <id>apache_snapshots_repo</id>
        <url>http://repository.apache.org/snapshots</url>
        <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
        <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
    </repository>
```

I took that repository from the [Dependency Repository Locations](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/commons-text/dependencies.html) section of the documentation of commons-text. However, still the dependency cannot be resolved by maven.

So which is the right dependency & repository I should configure in order to work with Apache commons-text ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to pull down the source and build it yourself. It appears that no artifacts have been deployed to [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ccommons-text) or the [Apache snapshots repository](http://repository.apache.org/snapshots).

FWIW, there hasn't been any significant development on that code since [May 2015](https://github.com/apache/commons-text/commits/master).

Answer (score 0):

I'm happy to write that development [has resumed](https://github.com/apache/commons-text/commits/master) for Apache Commons Text, and version  1.0 was [recently released.](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/commons-user/201703.mbox/browser)

It can now be imported normally. Keep in mind that you need to change the version from ***0.1-SNAPSHOT*** (as in the OP's question) to ***1.0***.

Here is its page on [Maven Central.](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-text/1.0)

(full disclosure - I also contributed to this project)